# Drop shadow - no rounded corners or blurring to shadow

Tags: css, roundedcorners-dropshadow

I read about the css box shadow property, from here:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

I want to use a similar shadow to: `.one-edge-shadow`. 
The problem is that I don't want the corners of the shadow to be blurred (and rounded).

How can I achieve that? (preferably elegantly).

**EDIT:** 
Comparison image: http://new.tsaviation.com/images/cpm155/drop-shadow-vs-bottom-shading.jpg

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already? and what exactly you want?

Comment: well, I THOUGHT this would be an easy post.  Here is a link to a comparison: http://new.tsaviation.com/images/cpm155/drop-shadow-vs-bottom-shading.jpg

Comment: Thanks, I think I understood your request, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to have a bottom shadow, that doesn't have a radius property on its bottom corners, right?

If so, you could "attach" a "shadow" that is basically a div with a gradient background.

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/inotoh/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Trick shadow -->
  <div id="box">
    <div class="shadow-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box{
  width:5em;
  height:5em;
  background-color:#6c6c6c;
  margin:5em auto;
}

/* New shadow element */
.shadow-bottom{
  position:relative;
  top:5em;/*height of box*/
  height:25%;
  width:100%;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```